# Expand Wordpress gallery shortcode to actual HTML img tags

Tags: wordpress, export, gallery

I've got a self-hosted Wordpress blog with hundreds of posts, most of which use the default [gallery] shortcode to show images that were uploaded for each post.

I now want to export these posts using the default Export All Content feature to get an XML file of all the posts' content, with images.  If you must know why, I want to use a blog printing service to print the blog in hardback book form (like http://www.blogbooker.com/wordpress.php)

Here's how post content and galleries currently come through:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
Post text here.
[gallery link="file"]
]]></content:encoded>
```

I'd like a way to expand the gallery into HTML, maybe with a one-time script, or a shortcode with PHP function, so the exported XML content would look more like this:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
Post text here.
<img src="http://www.blogname.com/wp-content/uploads/image1-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" /> 
<img src="http://www.blogname.com/wp-content/uploads/image2-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" />
<img src="http://www.blogname.com/wp-content/uploads/image3-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" />
]]></content:encoded>
```

Any ideas on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Sory, but it might be impossible :(. Perhaps if You create Your own xml export script and get it to expand shortcodes, than it might work.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a problem lots of people would have though - one of the many issues with [gallery].

Comment: Surely though there must be a way to replace galleries with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the current state of Wordpress or using any existing plugins.  The solution would be to write your own script to modify the WP database and convert gallery tags into HTML  and  tags for each image referenced in the gallery. When I do that, I will post a comment here.